# Using categories as multilingual mechanism

Tags: multi-language

Is there something wrong with the following approach.
I dislike installing plugins (with database access) on my wordpress.
But I want my wordpress to be multilingual .

What do you think about the option using the categories as the Language differentiation.
When some user creates a new post, he choose the language (Category).
In the theme Ill identify the language by the category.

Do you think it might work?

Thanks

Comment: Sketch your **full** szenario: How do you want to go about it? And please, rewrite your Q to something like "Is there something wrong with the following approach: _your full example_" to not get closed for being _not constructive (see close vote explanation).

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work that way. Taxonomy terms and posts are in a n:n relation: each term may be assigned to multiple posts and each post to multiple terms.

But you probably want to set just **one** main language per post – taxonomies are the wrong tool for that. Use post meta data or a multi-site plugin to assign a language to a post.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done this way, though I would use a custom taxonomy, not the default category taxonomy.  Realistically, though, there is no reason for you to not install a multi-lingual plugin.  If you're that wary of them, read the code for them before you install.  Wordpress comes with a whole slew of outstanding i18n features which you would be leaving completely by the wayside were you to use your proposed method.

Answer (score 0):

It might work, but with tons of limitations. Starting from the menus and widgets - setting them to show the correct language will be a big hassle.

I tried that approach myself intentionally - in order to write a "Doing it wrong" article - but I failed so quickly that I decided not to waste time anymore....

... and then it all ended up as https://www.WPGlobus.com/

So, the approach might work, but you better use a multilingual plugin.